# How to get text & Other tags  between specific tags using Jericho HTML parser?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I have a HTML file which contains a specific tag, e.g. `<TABLE cellspacing=0>` and the end tag is `</TABLE>`.  Now I want to get everything between those tags. I am using Jericho HTML parser in Java to parse the HTML. Is it possible to get the text & other tags between specific tags in Jericho parser?

For example:

```
<TABLE  cellspacing=0>    
  <tr><td>HELLO</td>  
  <td>How are you</td></tr>
</TABLE>
```

Answer:

```
<tr><td>HELLO</td>  
<td>How are you</td></tr>
```

Comment: The snippet below "answer" doesn't contain text only, it also contains HTML. So your requirement is a bit confusing. Do you want to extract nested HTML as given in your example or do you really want to extract text only, which would however result in `HELLO How are you`, without any HTML.

Comment: Hi Balus C,  I need everything between the <Table> tags.  is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to get HTML or do you want to get text? Your question title and body says that you want to get text. But your code example shows that you want to get HTML.

Comment: Thanks  for letting me know.  I have changed the title.  I want HTML tags & TEXT too.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have found the Element of your table, all you have to do is call getContent().toString().  Here's a quick example using your sample HTML:

```
Source source = new Source("<TABLE  cellspacing=0>\n" +
    "  <tr><td>HELLO</td>  \n" +
    "  <td>How are you</td></tr>\n" +
    "</TABLE>");

Element table = source.getFirstElement();
String tableContent = table.getContent().toString();

System.out.println(tableContent);
```

Output:

```
    <tr><td>HELLO</td>  
    <td>How are you</td></tr>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it more clear.  Also, I mis-spoke and the getContent() is only available for Elements, not all Segments (Segment is the superclass for all parsed nodes in Jericho).

Comment: I have the whole HTML file and then i want to parse it.  is it possible to get the specific tag from the whole HTML file?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to find it first.  Create your `Source` from the HTML document, then you get a `List` of tables like this: `List<Element> tables = source.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.TABLE);` For other ways to traverse the parsed document, have a look at the javadoc : http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/index.html.

Comment: so if there are multiple table in one HTML.  It will give me all the content between all the table tags?.

Comment: if your loop was :
`for(Element table : source.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.TABLE)) {
    System.out.println(table.getContent().toString());
}`
you would print out all of the content between the all of the table tags.

Answer (score 0):

Aby, I walk down the code for all elements  and show on screen. Maybe help you.

```
        List<Element> elementListTd = source.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.TD);

        //Scroll through the list of elements "td" page
        for (Element element : elementListTd) {
            if (element.getAttributes() != null) {
                String td = element.getAllElements().toString();
                String tag = "td";
                System.out.println("TD: " + td);
                System.out.println(element.getContent());
                String conteudoAtributo = element.getTextExtractor().toString();
                System.out.println(conteudoAtributo);

                if (td.contains(palavraCompara)) {
                    tabela.add(conteudoAtributo);
                }

            }
```