# Java Web Application - Get Between String

Tags: java, tags

I'm making a Java web application that finds text between tags using a .html file.

Example:

```
<title>Example</title>
```

Now the web application would open the .html file and find the text that is between the `<title>` tags which would be "Example".

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are number of html parsers available. Check them out [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers). Ofcourse there is always regex if that does not meet your need.

Comment: Similar Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625888/how-to-get-text-other-tags-between-specific-tags-using-jericho-html-parser

Comment: @CoolBeans: Ah, yes.  Because everyone knows you should [parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Close voters: You're going to have to do better than that.  "Not a Real Question" is not a synonym for "I don't like the question."

Comment: Regexpes ONLY work for simple cases.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: As I mentioned the first option is to use the HTML parsers. RegEx as I said is an option if someone really did not want to use one of the open source parser tools.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: That's a pretty highly voted answer. Good to read. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find detailed answer to go about doing this but high-level ideas. So here is my idea, write a servlet that takes a URL as a parameter and then use the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) lib to fetch that url and parse the title tag. Very easy if you use a good parser like jsoup.

```
Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get().select("title")
```

Comment: Please consider an [RFC 2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) compliant example, such as [http://www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Comment: @trashgod, not sure what you mean? there is a link on the post that links to jsoup. is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To get the website source code via scraping:

```
String targetPage = site;

                if(targetPage.contains("https://"))
                {
                } else {
                    targetPage = "https://".concat(targetPage);
                }

                System.out.println();

                //System.out.print(targetPage);

                System.out.println();

                URL wiki = new URI(targetPage).toURL();

                URLConnection yc = wiki.openConnection();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                    yc.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;

                String line = "";

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

                    line += inputLine;

                in.close();
```

From there, you can use the substring method to find everything in between :

```
line.substring("</title>","</title>")
```

You can do the same String manipulation by reading the .html file too